# R divide column elements by length

Tags: r

A relatively simple problem but I cant fix my code to do it.
I have a data frame `data` with a column `values` where a `list` of absolute frequencies are saved.
My goal is to iterate over the `data` and recalculate from the absolute respective relative frequencies. Here, we wave to keep in mind that each row is of different size.
My code:

```
data <- collected_data %>% 
  summarise(values = list(with(cur_data(), hist(x, breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 5), plot = FALSE)$values)))
```

Here an output from `dput`:

```
structure(list(scenario = "aa", pr = "all", rep = "2", 
    breaks = list(c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 
    55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 
    125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 
    185, 190, 195, 200, 205, 210, 215, 220, 225, 230, 235, 240, 
    245, 250, 255)), values = list(c(94301L, 97127L, 229783L, 
    64730L, 44546L, 22114L, 14761L, 10622L, 8038L, 6628L, 5632L, 
    5092L, 4306L, 3833L, 3580L, 3242L, 2899L, 2531L, 2189L, 1962L, 
    1769L, 1555L, 1312L, 1153L, 1023L, 853L, 775L, 664L, 544L, 
    418L, 385L, 331L, 279L, 195L, 121L, 109L, 81L, 60L, 40L, 
    28L, 16L, 13L, 7L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L))), .Names = c("scenario", 
"pr", "rep", "breaks", "values"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
), groups = structure(list(scenario = "e4", pr = "all", 
    .rows = structure(list(1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), .Names = c("scenario", "pr", 
".rows"), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

In the end, my expected output should have instead of the column with absolute frequencies, a column with relative frequencies. To do this I should divide each vector from column values with its length, but I cant do it.

Comment: maybe i am doing something wrong but it seems to me, that your dput()-data doesn't work as i think you want it to

Comment: is the sum of the vector in `values` equal to the total number of records?